# How to read the attributes of a class with c#?

Tags: c#, class, properties, metadata

I have a class where I define one constant from another class would read these constants or the content of attributes and properties of the class . Something like read the metadata of the class.
something like this:

```
 namespace Ventanas._01Generales
 {
 class Gral_Constantes
 {
    public class Cat_Productos
    {
        public const String Tabla_Productos = "Cat_Productos";
        public const String Campo_Producto_ID = "Producto_ID";
    }
    public class Cat_Grupos_Productos
    {
        public const String Tabla_Grupos_Productos = "Cat_Grupos_Productos";
        public const String Campo_Grupo_Producto_ID = "Grupo_Producto_ID";
    }

 }
}
```

in other class for example some like this

```
 namespace Ventanas._01Generales
 {
 class Pinta_Ventana
 {
   public void Crea_Insert()
   {
     foreach(Properties p in Cat_Producto.Properties)
     {
       miControl.Text = p.value; //show "Cat_Grupos_Productos"
       miControl.Name = p.value; //show Tabla_Grupos_Productos
     }
   }

 }
 }
```

Comment: It is not a property.  Keep trying, it is the next one you'd consider.

Comment: And what's wrong with using a list or a dictionary or somesuch?

Answer (score 1):

You need `Type.GetProperties` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx)) This code will work:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeof(Cat_Producto).GetProperties())
{
   ...
}
```

Now a few caveats:

1. You are using **reflection** which is really slow, and the fact that you are using it indicates you are likely doing something terribly wrong.
2. If you output the way your sample code does, only the last property's information will be visible, since you never let the UI update.
3. Your code doesn't actually have properties, they have const fields, so this code wouldn't return any of them. Make them properties for this method to work. You can use `Type.GetFields` if you want the fields version.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Perhaps. I did notice that after my initial post and edited it in. Of course, it would be nice if they told me that in addition to downvoting so I can correct it... Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to use the System.Reflection namespace. If you are interested in getting the names of the public const strings, you will need to use MemberInfo. This should get you started:

```
MemberInfo[] members = typeof(MyClass).GetMembers();

        foreach(MemberInfo m in members)
        {
            //do something with m.Name
            Console.WriteLine(m.Name);
        }
```

Comment: That would get you a lot more than just those strings... It is another viable option though, as long as you filter for methods/properties as necessary.